# Quando dou select numa tabela qualquer do meu banco FIREBIRD , Não consigo "decifrar" os varchar

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird

[image: Campo varchar firebird]

Entao , estou com problemas com esse banco , tento dar um select . em qualquer tabela que dou select  os varchar ficam desse jeito como vcs podem ver .

ja mudei o charset pra tudo quer jeito e continuou no mesmo problema 
[image: charset]
estou usando o IBexpert

Comment: Será que não é porque quem modelou o banco e o sistema que usa este banco não criou diretamente uma encriptação própria dos dados?

Comment: possivelmente isso que deve ter acontecido .  no caso  eu n entendo muito bem sobre esse assunto , mais , no programa sera que n tem a desencriptação desses dados?

Comment: Somente quem criou o programa poderá lhe fornecer o algorítimo para decifrar, até é possível ficar fazendo testes até quebrar, mas levaria dias e dependeria do algorítimo.

Comment: quero pegar esses dados e colocar no meu aplicativo   para  minha loja , para controlar estoque  e fazer as minhas pesquisas de preço  , nada de mais , meu aplicativo esta pronto so falta pegar esses dados e inserir nele   na vdd pegar esses dado jogar para o Mysql  cuja o aplicativo sincroniza com  o webservice

Comment: esse aquivo seria oque Guilherme? UM .DLL ?

Comment: Que arquivo? Não tem como pegar os dados sem decodifica-los e realmente só o autor do aplicativo anterior poderá lhe informar qual algorítimo ele usou para isto.

Comment: seria tipo esse caso ? https://www.dirceuresende.com/blog/como-remover-acentuacao-e-caracteres-especiais-de-uma-string-no-sql-server/

Comment: Acho que não, a questão ae é no aplicativo que usava (usa) este banco, não tem nada ver com algo pronto, o criador do software é unico que vai saber lhe informar com precisão, tem mil e umas maneiras de codificar e cada maneira pode aceitar milhões de "hashs" aleatórias, o tipo de encriptação e possivel hash que o autor do software usou só ele vai saber dizer. Se fosse possivel decodificar com um qualquer coisa de Sql então não seria "seguro". Como disse, creio que só vc entrando em contato com o autor do software.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento , mals aew por vc perder um pouco do seu tempo , mais vc me ajudou muito pode ter certeza

Comment: duvido que o autor me passar isso , meu pequeno pprojeto foi pro lixo

Comment: Não custa tentar, pergunte se ao menos tem uma maneira de fazer backup de maneira limpa, converse com seu cliente para pressionar o autor do software, talvez ajude. Até mais o/

Comment: Abraço  aew , PAZ